# why not uint32 instead of int64?

Tags: go

There are some similar designs in the go interface. For example, the results of reading and writing can only be values `>= 0`. Why not just use the `unsigned int` type? What is the purpose of using signed types?

```golang
// The Copy function uses ReaderFrom if available.
type ReaderFrom interface {
    ReadFrom(r Reader) (n int64, err error)
}

// The Copy function uses WriterTo if available.
type WriterTo interface {
    WriteTo(w Writer) (n int64, err error)
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that int64 is more efficient on most modern hardware.  Of course they could use uint64, but why bother? Nobody's ever going to read 18 exabytes in a single operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29658892/13860

Comment: First of all: Such functions should use the nativ integer type, that is either `int` or `uint` and not a specific bitsize variant. So it is either `int` or `uint`. What lots of people do get wrong is: `uint` is **not** a "positive integer number". A uint is a bitpattern, it is _not_ per se a number. (The fact that +, - etc are defined on uints doesn make them conceptualiy numbers).

Comment: Working with uints as if they were numbers is a loaded footgun as over/underflow occurs at _both_ _ends_ of the value range, that is 0 and "a lot". Values around 0 are very common and lead to ugly bugs. (Overflow happens for ints too, but on modern systems a int is 64 bits and it overflows at _highly_ _uncommon_ values but not around the common 0). It is wrong to treat uints as "non negative integers": You gain nothing at the increased risk of underflow bugs.

Comment: @Volker Can you submit it to the answer area so that novices can get a correct idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a good explanation in the book *Go Programming Language (A. Donovan, B. Kernighan)*:

> Although Go provides unsigned numbers and arithmetic, we tend to use
>   the signed `int` form even for quantities that can’t be negative, such
>   as the length of an array, though `uint` might seem a more obvious
>   choice. Indeed, the built-in `len` function returns a signed `int`, as in
>   this loop which announces prize medals in reverse order:

```
medals := []string{"gold", "silver", "bronze"}
    for i := len(medals) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
    fmt.Println(medals[i]) // "bronze", "silver", "gold"
}
```

> The alternative would be calamitous. If `len` returned an unsigned
>   number, then `i` too would be a `uint`, and the condition `i >= 0`
>   would always be true by definition. After the third iteration, in
>   which `i == 0`, the `i--` statement would cause `i` to become not −1,
>   but the maximum `uint` value, and the evaluation of `medals[i]` would
>   fail at run time, or panic, by attempting to access an element outside
>   the bounds of the slice. For this reason, **unsigned numbers tend to be
>   used only when their bitwise operators or peculiar arithmetic
>   operators are required**, as when implementing bit sets, parsing binary
>   file.